# boost custom formatter using boost bind to method taking only one paramerter

Tags: c++, regex, boost, bind

I'm trying to use boost::regex_replace with a custom formatter. I need to pass a method from an object because some member is needed in the replacing function.

The signature of my replacing method is:

```
std::string MyObject::ReplaceStr(
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match) const
```

When calling `regex_replace`, I pass these arguments:

```
std::string replaced = regex_replace(
    orig_string, replace_pattern, 
    boost::bind<std::string>(&MyObject::ReplaceStr, this, _1));
```

The problem is when regex_replace calls the format method on the match result, the Functor used is the one taking 3 parameters(Custom formatter can be string, unary, binary or ternary function). I think it is due to the fact that boost::bind somewhat hides arity of a function.

The reason why I think it is due the the arity disappearing is because when binding with

```
std::string replaced = regex_replace(
    orig_string, replace_pattern,       
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MyObject::ReplaceStr), this));
```

the right functor(the one using the unary function) is called.

I could also probably just use a ternary function in my object to bind to and then it would probably work but for the sake of understanding and using boost::bind can someone explain if I understood correctly and if not provide the right explanation.

Bonus point if I can make it work with boost bind.

**EDIT:** I forgot to tell that it crashes when I use `boost::bind` due to selecting the wrong method signature. Here's a code snippet to reproduce the behavior I tried to explain:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class MyObject
{
public:
    void ReplacePattern()
    {
        const std::string testString = "${value_to_replace}extra_value";

        boost::regex replace_pattern("(\\$\\{(.*?)\\})");
        std::string replaced = regex_replace(testString, replace_pattern, boost::bind(&MyObject::ReplaceStr, this, _1));

        cout << "Replaced: " << replaced << endl;
    }

    std::string ReplaceStr(
        boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match) const
    {
        return "replaced_value";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyObject obj;
    obj.ReplacePattern();


    char dummy[1];
    cin.getline(dummy, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample code to reproduce your problem ? I've tried to understand it but I really don't. Your `boost::bind` usage seems fine to me, and as long as there's only one placeholder, the resulting functor should be a unary function that the compiler wouldn't allow to call with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use boost::function to avoid ambiguity:

```
boost::function<std::string (boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>)> function =
    boost::bind(&MyObject::ReplaceStr, this, _1);
std::string replaced = regex_replace(testString, replace_pattern, function);
```

Comment: I feel sort of ashamed by the cleverness of this answer but it works perfectly. Kudos.